# Explicit regexp in if statement not equivalent to same regexp as var with (GBP) pound sign

Tags: javascript, regex, intellij-idea

Bit of a noob at JS so I might be missing something fundamental but this seems to be a bit odd:

```
var r = /£/;
r.test("!£$%^&*()_+1234567890-="); //yields false
/£/.test("!£$%^&*()_+1234567890-="); //yields true
```

It's only after debugging in Intellij I found some unicode madness, but even so I think these should both yield the same result?

[image: regexp doesn't look the same]

I've fixed this in my code by explicitly using `/£/` but would be good to know why this happens.

Comment: Sorry, cannot repro. Both return true (in Chrome, Win7).

Comment: That's weird... Def happening on my machine (debugging via Intellij) - wonder if its an artefact of the IDE? That would be bad...

Comment: Maybe you copy pasted the pound sign from somewhere else that have hidden character.

Comment: I typed it in via an input field

Comment: Yes I think this is an Intellij issue - posting answer below in case anyone else comes across it. Thanks both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is both a unicode and Intellij issue. If I have a plain old html file with a password field, and then get the result like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    postFunc = function() {
        var pw1 = document.getElementById("password1").value;
        var r1 = /£/;
        alert(r1.test(pw1)); //false
        alert(/£/.test(pw1)); //false
        alert(/\u00A3/.test(pw1)); //true
    }
</script>
```

First 2 alerts both say "false" but adding a "Watch" in the debugger equivalent to those tests gives the result as described in the original question. Will raise to Jetbrains.

To fix my code I used the unicode for £, which works as expected. Still not sure what's happening there.